# how to fix TypeError: class() takes no arguments problem?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a class name RangePrime and it's instance attributes should print out the range of them and finally appear an issue. How to fix them?

```
class RangePrime:
def range_list(self,a,b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    x = []
    if b < a:
        x.extend(range(b, a))
        x.append(a)
    else:
        x.extend(range(a, b))
        x.append(b)
    return x
```

after i ran this -> range_prime = RangePrime(1, 5) and it start to appear
TypeError: RangePrime() takes no arguments

I should get the following result:

```
>>> range_prime = RangePrime(1, 5)
>>> range_prime.range_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It really looks you want `range_list` to actually be named `__init__`, so that `RangePrime(1, 5)` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you have mixed using functions without a `class` definition and at the same time misdefining the functions within the `class` by lacking an `__init__()`. I have modified your code a bit to account for the `class` and its functions, so the intention of your code remains the same. Kindly try:

```
class RangePrime():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
    def range_list(self):
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        x = []
        if b < a:
            x.extend(range(b, a))
            x.append(a)
        else:
            x.extend(range(a, b))
            x.append(b)
        return x
```

Which when running:

```
range_prime = RangePrime(1, 5)
range_prime.range_list()
```

Returns:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

create object of the class first and then pass those parameter in your class method then it will work

```
ob=RangePrime()

print(ob.range_list(1,5))
```